# Creating Indexes After Loading Large Table (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ssis

I drop the table indexes when loading the tables in SSIS to speed up the import process.  Is there a faster or best practice on adding the indexes back?  I am using a simple create index and it takes a long time.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [ALTER INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql) documentation yet? You don't need to drop and recreate indexes.

Comment: I am dropping and recreating indexes for import performance.  The tables load twice as fast when the indexes are dropped.